# Logging actions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What´s the best way to log each action executed in VBA? Is there some built-in Windows object that already does this that I can use?

(I'm not referring to user actions)

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing built-in. What do you want the log to look like? For example, what **exactly** would you expect to be entered in the log for `Range("A1").Select`?

Comment: @Rory I would want the log to say, "Range A1 selected"

Comment: Then I'd say you have a **phenomenal** amount of work ahead of you! ;)

Comment: Turn the macro recorder on, after completion parse the produced code. O_o

Comment: Could you please elaborate what actions you are talking about, post the exact list.

Comment: For example, every time I run a loop on something, or check if a sheet exists, or if a cell is blank, or if a new array is declared, etc. Basically, a play-by-play of each line or block of code that is run in the backend

Answer (score 0):

This will log actions typed into cells.  Right-click your sheet and paste the code into the window that opens..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$b$400")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Select
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Target.Address
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Target.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = InputBox("You've made a change to the Rates tab. Please enter your name here for historical purposes.")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not referring to user actions. I basically need a play-by-play of each line of code that is run in the backend